# Calculus quotient rule

Tags: calculus

$g(x)=\frac{x^{1/4}}{x^3+1}$, find $g'(x)$. Use the quotient rule.

My attempt was:

\begin{align}g'(x)&=\frac{\frac{1}{4}(x^{-3/4})(x^3+1)-(3x^2)(x^{1/4})}{(x^3+1)^2}\\
g'(x)&=\frac{(x^3+1)-(3x^2)(x^{1/4})}{4(x^{3/4})(x^3+1)^2}\end{align}

I am $100\ \%$ sure of the denominator which is the easy part, but or the numerator I am stuck.

Comment: In the second step, when you moved the "4" and the factor $ \ x^{-3/4} \ $ to the denominator, you forgot to _also_ take  factors of  $ \ \frac{1}{4} \ $ and $ \ x^{-3/4} \ $ from the _second_ term in the numerator.  That term should become $ \ 4 \ (3x^2) \ (x^1) \ $ or  $ \ 12x^3 \ $  ...

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^{\frac 14}}{x^3+1} &=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(x^{\frac 14})(x^3+1)+(x^{\frac 14})\frac{d}{dx} (x^3+1)}{(x^3+1)^2} \\
&=\frac{\frac 14x^{-\frac 34}(x^3+1)+x^{\frac 14}(3x^2)}{(x^3+1)^2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$g'(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{4}(x^{-3/4})(x^3+1)-(3x^2)(x^{1/4})}{(x^3+1)^2}$ this step is correct. But in next step you should multiply both the terms in numerator by $4x^{\frac{3}{4}}$ I think, the numerator will be $-11x^3+1$.

Comment: why downvote? I just corrected the calculation, is there something wrong in my answer?